# SyntaxError on using SVG as React Component

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am experiencing an error, and I can't seem to find any solution since it looks like no one has experienced this yet.

I read in create-react-app documentation that you can load SVG files as React components [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files#adding-svgs).

My sample usage looks like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as Caret } from '../icons/caret.svg';

//other parts of code
  <Caret />
//other parts of code
```

However, I get an error like this:

```
./src/icons/caret.svg (./node_modules/@svgr/webpack/lib?-prettier,-svgo!./src/icons/caret.svg
const pBabelTransform = async jsCode => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                              ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

My `react-scripts` is at version 2.1.3 by the way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What occurs if you remove the lines related to the `jsCode`? The error persists? If positive, then share more about the piece of code for better understand. Maybe the error is related to the way you are using the Caret component.

Comment: I believe there's no more to that. Based on documentation of `create-react-app`, it's ready to use and doesn't need any config or whatsover.

Comment: That's correct, but you mean that you are getting that error just after import the SVG as a React Component, haven't you used the Caret component anywhere in the code?

Comment: It's my first time using it.

Comment: Have you tried other svg asset?